# Update value by using DataTables row-reorder in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I need to update the `OrderIndex` value inside database by row-reorder function in datatables ([www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net)).

I have already searched in google and I found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331986/Table-Row-Drag-and-Drop-in-ASP-NET-MVC-jQuery-Data). I followed all of the steps but it didn't help.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

### ViewModel

```
public class GenderDDUpdateOrderIndexViewModel
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
    }
```

### Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRowIndex(GenderDDUpdateOrderIndexViewModel model, int? Id, int? fromPosition, int toPosition, string direction)
 {
   using (var ctx = new ApplicationIdentityDbContext())
      {                         
        if (direction == "back")
          {
            var GenderList = ctx.GenderDD
                       .Where(c => (toPosition <= c.OrderIndex && c.OrderIndex <= fromPosition))
                       .ToList();

              foreach (var gender in GenderList)
                  {
                   gender.OrderIndex++;
                  }
                }
                else
                {
            var GenderList = ctx.GenderDD
                       .Where(c => (fromPosition <= c.OrderIndex && c.OrderIndex <= toPosition))
                       .ToList();
               foreach (var gender in GenderList)
                  {
                   gender.OrderIndex--;
                  }
                }
         ctx.GenderDD.First(c => c.Id == Id).OrderIndex = toPosition;
         await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
         return View();
     }
```

### DataTables Initialisation

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var table = $('#GenderIndex').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                rowReorder: {
                 snapX: 10  
                }

            });         

       });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using v.1.10 - that article you've linked to is for v1.9 which won't work. See [here](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/) for info about this.

Comment: @Thanks. Yes I'm using the latest version. I'm getting the following error:0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'rowReordering'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Above mentioned plug-in won't work since it's extremely old. You can easily use [DataTables RowReorder](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) extension.
You don't need to write such a long action method since many of those parameters are not supported by the latest version of DataTables.

### Controller

```
public void UpdateRow(GenderDDUpdateOrderIndexViewModel model, int Id, int fromPosition, int toPosition)
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationIdentityDbContext())
            {
               var GenderList = ctx.GenderDD.ToList();
               ctx.GenderDD.First(c => c.OrderIndex == Id).OrderIndex = toPosition;
               ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

### jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var table = $('#GenderIndex').DataTable({
            rowReorder: true,
              "paging": true,
              "pagingType": "full_numbers",
              fixedHeader: true,
              select: false,
              "order": [[0, "asc"]],
              "info": true,
              "processing": false,
              "responsive": true,
              "searching": true,
              "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
              "language": {
                  "lengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                  "zeroRecords": "No records found",
                  "infoEmpty": "No records found",
                  "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
              },
              "columnDefs": [
                  { "orderable": false, "targets": 8 }
              ]
        });

        $('#GenderIndex').on('row-reorder.dt', function (dragEvent, data, nodes) {
            for (var i = 0, ien = data.length ; i < ien ; i++) {
                var rowData = table.row(data[i].node).data();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/GenderDD/UpdateRow',
                    data: { Id: rowData[0], fromPosition: data[i].oldData, toPosition: data[i].newData },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
                }
        });
   </script>
```

Comment: I recently implemented this solution, but had to change a few things:
`rowData[0]` becomes `rowData.id`,
`data[i].oldData` becomes `data[i].oldPosition`,
`data[i].newData` becomes `data[i].newPosition`