# JavaScript runtime error during DataTables rowReordering (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using the following jQuery to initialize [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#GenderIndex').dataTable().rowReordering({ sURL: "/GenderDD/UpdateRow" });
    });
</script>
```

During drag and drop (Reordering) I'm getting the following error message:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression: #

You can find the rowReordering plugin [Here](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js).

---

1. I really don't understand this error message
2. Has anyone ever used `rowReordering` with the latest DataTables
   version?

Answer (score 2):

1. The error "*unrecognized expression: #*" means that you not have defined an indexing column. The RowReordering plugin needs a column with unique numbers it can populate to the `<tr>`'s as `id`'s it then use to distinguish between rows. You have no such column, therefore this plugin tries to perform an `#id` selector without id - `$("#")`.
2. You need to use the new **RowReorder** plugin if you want to have RowReordering in dataTables 1.10.x -> **http://cdn.datatables.net/#RowReorder** fiddle here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/006d4of9/**. The new and better plugin is more flexible but still needs an indexing column - it does not throw errors if you have forgotten to define one, though.

Comment: Thanks David for your complete explanation. I would be more than happy to use RowReorder plugin but I can't find any example on how to add a action method URL like above. I need to reorder then also update the database. Example, if one row had Index number 2 but now it's moved to 3 it should be saved that way.

Comment: you can listen to the `row-reorder` event, by that you can be aware of rows being moved and call a serverside script -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand when you say call a serverside script. Because I don't know how should I call that URL. I can see in your example where after each move a prompt window appears but how can I save those changes? I'm quite new to jQuery specially when it comes to connect serverside to jQuery.

Comment: I made this post 2 days ago where I was stuck in another part of datatables.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469000/update-value-by-using-datatables-row-reorder-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: @CodeMaster - use `$.ajax` and pass the dragevent `data` as `data`, like in this scheme -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/659/ - on serverside unpack `data` and you have all the info, see this resource -> **http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/**

Comment: Thanks so much David. Let me test this.

Comment: I believe I'm lost. You method requires to return JSON but my current action method has no reference to return JSON data... Your answers are great and there is no doubt about it but I'm kind of confused about that...

Comment: @CodeMaster - http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/659/ was just a way to invoke the serverside script you want to update the database. Your script does not need to return anything back in any format.  I suggest to just pass the event `data` since that imho is easiest nonconfusing way. You can unpack the passed object back in C# / ASP very easy, so you serverside know what row is moved from where to where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94095/discussion-between-codemaster-and-davidkonrad).

Comment: @CodeMaster, not so good - I am on work right now, we are having visitors from other countries - can be off from SO for ½ and whole hours ....

Comment: No problem, I will try my best to address this issue. Thanks again

Comment: Based on your solution, I was able to update the rows however in some cases it assigns the same row number, for example I have: Female (1), Male(2), Unknown (3). When 3 moves to 1, it gives 1 to both then I can't sort them since two rows have the same Index number.

Comment: Is there any need to have "direction" to identify the movement?